# wordpress-plugin-in-div

Tags: wordpress

i just want to ask that i want to add a contact form plugin in a div which i am having in footer.
the plugin i want to add is contact form and for using it, it says that i have to put the short code i-e [contact_form] in any page or post. but the problem is i want a code of php for this so that i can place this contact form in the div of my own choice.
my div in footer like like this

```
 <div id="ContactUs">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>

    <input name="" type="text" class="textBox1" />
    <p>Name*</p>
    <input name="" type="text" class="textBox2" />
    <p>Email*</p>
    <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" class="textArea1">
    </textarea>
    <a href="#" class="SendBtn">
    <img src="images/send.png" />
    </a>



    </div><!--end of contactus-->
```

now i want to add this plugin in between this div instead of form i made manually.

Comment: Please improve the question title.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function if you want to use a shortcode outside the post editor.

Given the name of required shortcode, [contact_form], you can rewrite code as follows:

```
<div id="ContactUs">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact_form]'); ?>
</div><!--end of contactus-->
```

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help! Please accept the answer if you find it useful.